# how to remember all the occurrences in REGEX?

Tags: php, regex

There is a line

```
int gg = 665 j h = 78;
```

Check it on the condition and memorize the characters gg, j, h.
Wrote regex:

```
/^\s*int\s+(?:\s*([a-z]+)\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+\s*){0,1})+;$/
```

Get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => int gg =665 j h = 78;
    ),
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => h
    )
)
```

It turned out that only remember the last entry, I want to catch all the others too.

Comment: Another reason why regular expressions are not parsers.

Comment: can your give me an advice? The task is check the string against a pattern and remember it the necessary elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `preg_match_all`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: i use this:
preg_match_all('/^\s*целое\s+(?:\s*([a-z]+)\s*(?:=\s*[0-9]+\s*){0,1})+;$/',$line,$r);
        print_r($r);

Comment: Well, I am no regEx expert, but I have used reg_match_all to store all occurrences of a pattern. Perhaps there is an issue with your pattern string.